# Need to Share record with Subordinate

Tags: sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I am using Salesforce community (Digital Experience). In which I have user and their manager. Now I want to share all records owned by manager to their subordinate. Is there any point and click way available here. I know that I can create Apex Sharing and using trigger/flow can share record. But I prefer if I can create sharing rules instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sharing Sets for communities.
It is possible to use Sharing Rules as well.